# Updating a variable on component load

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable in side of my Event 1 component that is equal to Another variable inside of data.service which holds a string.

I am trying to update the data.service string to 'Event 2' when the event 2 component is loaded.

I have tried the following code which does not seem to work. I have tried calling this in ngAfterViewInit and from a button.

Event 1 Component:

`public Title = this.dataservice.Title;`

Data.service:

`public Title = "Event 1";`

Event 2 Component:

````
changeTitle(){
      this.dataService.Title = 'Event 2';
      console.log("CHANGE TITLE");
    }


    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       this.changeTitle();
    }```
````

Comment: Show `dataService`

Comment: you've to set title variable as observable subject to update it through components. check this> https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: I've made a video to show how it behaves: youtu.be/afojtw0k_Js

Answer (score 0):

In dataService.ts

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class DataService {
    updatedTitle = new EventEmitter<string>();
    onUpdateTitle(title) { // call this method on button click
       // can be stored in a variable
       this.updatedTitle.emit(title);
    }
}
```

in component.ts

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
    title: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.updatedTitle.subscribe((res) => { 
            this.title = res;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but only on the second call of the component.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your point. ngOnInit will be called each time you load the component.

Comment: I have to go in and out of the component twice for it to load in.

Comment: Have you used any condition to load the component?

Comment: I have a a set of cards that loads each new component through a button click.

Comment: I've made a video to show how it behaves: https://youtu.be/afojtw0k_Js

Comment: When the button is clicked, an event will be emitted with the latest value. In component, we will get the value by subscribing the event and update the DOM